# Virtual Bug with CPP

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having some issues with C++ using it with binary tests, i'm learning binary search trees, i'm getting these erros, note : i didn't code the functions, i'm first trying to compile it with random returns.

```
:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g "C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL Árvore Binária\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL Árvore Binária\testVpl.exe" -lgtest -std=c++20
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_Inicializacao_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:6:49: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
    6 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:14:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>':
   14 | class MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria : public ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:4,
                 from C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:30:18: note:     'bool ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::vazia() const [with T = int]'
   30 |     virtual bool vazia() const = 0;
      |                  ^~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:36:17: note:     'int ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::quantidade() const [with T = int]'
   36 |     virtual int quantidade() const = 0;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:43:18: note:     'bool ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::contem(T) const [with T = int]'
   43 |     virtual bool contem(T chave) const = 0;
      |                  ^~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:50:32: note:     'std::optional<int> ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::altura(T) const [with T = int]'
   50 |     virtual std::optional<int> altura(T chave) const = 0;
      |                                ^~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:70:30: note:     'std::optional<_Tp> ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::filhoEsquerdaDe(T) const [with T = int]'
   70 |     virtual std::optional<T> filhoEsquerdaDe(T chave) const = 0;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:77:30: note:     'std::optional<_Tp> ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::filhoDireitaDe(T) const [with T = int]'
   77 |     virtual std::optional<T> filhoDireitaDe(T chave) const = 0;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:83:40: note:     'ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::emOrdem() const [with T = int]'
   83 |     virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* emOrdem() const = 0;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:89:40: note:     'ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::preOrdem() const [with T = int]'
   89 |     virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* preOrdem() const = 0;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp:95:40: note:     'ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::posOrdem() const [with T = int]'
   95 |     virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* posOrdem() const = 0;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_PreOrdem_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:36:49: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
   36 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_EmOrdem_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:53:49: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
   53 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_PosOrdem_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:70:49: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
   70 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_Insercao_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:87:49: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
   87 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest_Remocao_Test::TestBody()':
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:135:43: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
  135 |     ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Saint\Dropbox\PC\Documents\UFSC\Estrutura de Dados\VPL �rvore Bin�ria\main.cpp:183:18: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>'
  183 |     arvore = new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

These are my errors

these are the files

The hpp file

```
#define ARVORE_DE_BUSCA_BINARIA_HPP

#include "MinhaListaEncadeada.hpp"
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
struct Nodo
{
    T chave;
    int altura{0};
    Nodo* filhoEsquerda{nullptr};
    Nodo* filhoDireita{nullptr};
};

template<typename T>
class ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria
{
protected:
    Nodo<T>* _raiz;

public:
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria();
    virtual ~ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria();

    /**
     * @brief Verifica se a arvore esta vazia
     * @return Verdade se a arvore esta vazia.
     */
    virtual bool vazia() const = 0;
    
    /**
     * @brief Retornar quantidade de chaves na arvore
     * @return Numero natural que representa a quantidade de chaves na arvore
     */
    virtual int quantidade() const = 0;
    
    /**
     * @brief Verifica se a arvore contem uma chave
     * @param chave chave a ser procurada na arvore
     * @return Verdade se a arvore contem a chave
     */
    virtual bool contem(T chave) const = 0;
    
    /**
     * @brief Retorna a altura da (sub)arvore
     * @param chave chave que é raiz da (sub)arvore cuja altura queremos. Se chave é nula, retorna a altura da arvore.
     * @return Numero inteiro representando a altura da (subarvore). Se chave nao esta na arvore, retorna std::nullopt
     */
    virtual std::optional<int> altura(T chave) const = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Insere uma chave na arvore
     * @param chave chave a ser inserida
     */        
    virtual void inserir(T chave) = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Remove uma chave da arvore
     * @param chave chave a removida
     * @return Retorna a chave removida ou nullptr se a chave nao esta na arvore
     */        
    virtual void remover(T chave) = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Busca a chave do filho a esquerda de uma (sub)arvore
     * @param chave chave da arvore que eh pai do filho a esquerda
     * @return Chave do filho a esquerda. Se chave nao esta na arvore, retorna std::nullopt
     */
    virtual std::optional<T> filhoEsquerdaDe(T chave) const = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Busca a chave do filho a direita de uma (sub)arvore
     * @param chave chave da arvore que eh pai do filho a direita
     * @return Chave do filho a direita. Se chave nao esta na arvore, retorna nullptr
     */        
    virtual std::optional<T> filhoDireitaDe(T chave) const = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Lista chaves visitando a arvore em ordem
     * @return Lista encadeada contendo as chaves em ordem. 
     */
    virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* emOrdem() const = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Lista chaves visitando a arvore em pre-ordem
     * @return Lista encadeada contendo as chaves em pre-ordem. 
     */
    virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* preOrdem() const = 0;

    /**
     * @brief Lista chaves visitando a arvore em pos-ordem
     * @return Lista encadeada contendo as chaves em pos ordem. 
     */
    virtual ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* posOrdem() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria():
    _raiz{} // instancia _raiz com nullptr. Equivalente a _raiz{nullptr}
{}

template<typename T>
ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::~ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria() = default; //atribui destrutor padrao do C++.

#endif
```

That is my file, i didn't finish to code, but everytime i try to write i keep getting the same error.

```
#define MINHAARVOREDEBUSCABINARIA_HPP

#include "ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

/**
 * @brief Representa uma árvore binária de busca.
 * 
 * @tparam T O tipo de dado guardado na árvore.
 */
template<typename T>
class MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria : public ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>
{
    bool vazia()
    {
      if (ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::raiz == nullptr)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else return false;
    };

    int quantidade() 
    {
       return 5;
    };

    bool contem(T chave)
    {
        return true;
    }

    std::optional<int> altura(T chave)
    {
         return 5;
    };

    void inserir(T chave)
    {
      Nodo<T> * novo_nodo = new Nodo<T>();
      novo_nodo->chave = chave;
      novo_nodo->filhoDireita = nullptr;
      novo_nodo->filhoEsquerda = nullptr;

      Nodo<T>* raiz_da_arvore = ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<T>::_raiz; //Pegando a raiz da árvore binária
      if(raiz_da_arvore == NULL)
      {
        raiz_da_arvore = novo_nodo;
      }
      

    };

    void remover(T chave)
    {

    };

    std::optional<int> filhoEsquerdaDe(T chave)
    {
      return 5;
    };

   std::optional<int> filhoDireitaDe(T chave)
    {
       return 5;
    };

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* emOrdem() 
    {

    };

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* preOrdem() 
    {

    };

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<T>* posOrdem()
    {

    };
};

#endif
```

These are the binary tests. i should not change it.

```
#include "MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria.hpp"

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, Inicializacao)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->vazia());
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 0);

    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->contem(1));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->altura(1));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(1));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(1));
    
    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<int>* lista{arvore->emOrdem()};
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista != nullptr);
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista->estaVazia());
    delete lista;

    lista = arvore->preOrdem();
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista != nullptr);
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista->estaVazia());
    delete lista;

    lista = arvore->posOrdem();
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista != nullptr);
    ASSERT_TRUE(lista->estaVazia());
    delete lista;
    
    delete arvore;
}

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, PreOrdem)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<int>* const lista{arvore->preOrdem()};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 9})
        ASSERT_EQ(lista->retiraDoInicio(), e);

    delete lista;

    delete arvore;
}

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, EmOrdem)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<int>* const lista{arvore->emOrdem()};

    for (int const e : {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9})
        ASSERT_EQ(lista->retiraDoInicio(), e);

    delete lista;

    delete arvore;
}

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, PosOrdem)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    ListaEncadeadaAbstrata<int>* const lista{arvore->posOrdem()};

    for (int const e : {2, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7, 5})
        ASSERT_EQ(lista->retiraDoInicio(), e);

    delete lista;

    delete arvore;
}

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, Insercao)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* const arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->vazia());
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 7);

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(5));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(5), 2);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(5), 7);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(5), 3);

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(3));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(3), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(3), 4);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(3), 2);

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(7));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(7), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(7), 9);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(7), 6);

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(2));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(2), 0);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(2));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(2));

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(4));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(4), 0);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(4));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(4));

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(6));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(6), 0);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(6));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(6));

    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(9));
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(9), 0);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(9));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(9));

    delete arvore;  
}

TEST(ArvoreBinariaBuscaTest, Remocao)
{
    ArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>* arvore{new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>};

    for (int const e : {5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    //Testa remover folha
    arvore->remover(9);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->contem(9));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 6);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(7));
    
    //Testa remover folha
    arvore->remover(6);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->contem(6));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 5);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoDireitaDe(7));
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(7));
    
    //Testa remover raiz
    arvore->inserir(6);
    arvore->inserir(9);
    arvore->remover(5);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->contem(5));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 6);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(6), 7);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(6), 3);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(7), 9);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(7));

    //Testa remover nodo com filhoDireita sem descendente a esquerda
    arvore->inserir(5);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(4), 5);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(6), 3);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(4), 1);
    arvore->remover(3);
    ASSERT_TRUE(!arvore->contem(3));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 6);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(6), 4);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(6), 7);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->altura(6), 2);

    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoDireitaDe(4), 5);
    ASSERT_EQ(*arvore->filhoEsquerdaDe(4), 2);

    delete arvore;

    // Testa esvaziar a árvore.

    arvore = new MinhaArvoreDeBuscaBinaria<int>;

    for (int const e : {3, 2, 4})
        arvore->inserir(e);

    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 3);

    for (int const e : {3, 2, 4})
        arvore->remover(e);

    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 0);

    // Testa remover item não contido na árvore.

    arvore->inserir(2);
    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(2));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 1);

    arvore->remover(3);
    ASSERT_TRUE(arvore->contem(2));
    ASSERT_EQ(arvore->quantidade(), 1);

    delete arvore;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: `int quantidade() const` != `int quantidade()`.  The child class is not overriding the `const` versions of the pure virtual functions from the base class.

Comment: This is why you should use `override`.

Comment: Side note: always use English in your code (avoid your native language to name symbols), It can be very crippled version of English, but it will be easier to read for everyone. I know it may be not comfortable for you to force yourself to code in English, but this effort will pay off (literally).

Comment: Sorry guys, i already solve it, i was doing a lot of errors, i didn't see that the destructor was a virtual function, also, i forgot to use public:, i was writing it in portuguese because it is a university project, it must be in portuguese, sorry :(